# Preload lots of data not explicitly serializable, then send it to multiple worker instances

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a process that I run in many instances. Every 5 minutes, in each instance, I load a lot of data and configuration from several non-local sources. This puts a lot of unnecessary strain on the sources because I just need the same data for every instance.

So I thought I should make just one process that takes care of the loading and generating all the data structures necessary from that, and then send that finished 'package' to each of the worker-processes (each on separate machines/cloud machines!).

This 'package' object contains a lot of custom data structures and objects that are not specifically marked as serializable. I would not otherwise save the object over a long time so it can be assumed that the libraries of the loader and the workers are exactly the same. Is there any way I could still just copy the bits of the object to send to the worker instances, for example just using a binary download on request from a worker?

Comment: Is your question _"How can I serialize an object not explicitly marked serializable"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster I suppose. I explained my situation in case there are some shortcuts that can be made here (no long-term storage, only one version of the worker and loader etc)

Comment: You can do it other way around: provide something scale-able in between process and sources, to return cached source.